Does Italian.SE want hats?
Brace yourselves! As it did last year, Winter Bash is coming. From 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014, the Stack Exchange network sites are once again enhancing their already overwhelming charisma with the cunning use of really slick hats. 
Here’s a quick rundown of how the event works:

During the event period, users can earn hats for their avatar by completing tasks on the site, similar to the regular badge system
Users can earn multiple hats and choose which one to “wear”; this hat will appear with their avatar wherever their avatar is displayed on the site
Sites can opt out of the event, meaning no hats can be earned or displayed on their site
Individual users can opt out of the event, meaning they will not earn or see any hats anywhere on the Stack Exchange network 

Winter Bash is a fun and temporary way for the network to have a little fun during the holiday season. In some cases, however, it can interfere with the intended professional or academic tone of a site. That’s why we ask each site to choose whether or not they want to participate.
So, noble cohorts: should Italian participate in this year's Winter Bash? Let me know what you think below. Thanks!
Update 11/25/13: Hats it is!
Having heard much assent and no dissent, I've opted Italian in to Winter Bash 2013. Stay tuned!

There was a poll here! Anyway, I agree to allow hats, a bit of fancy features can never destroy our professional tone :-)!

I want a hat shaped like a boot!

As I said in one of deleted answer, I'm so professional I wanna wear a Pisa tower hat!

@GabrielePetronella "Pisano" is considered an insult in Livorno :-)

@Sklivvz a Duomo hat, better? ;)

@GabrielePetronella You should choose a hat representing your city, regardless of what people say :P! I also want a hat.

@martina well I'm actually from Milan, the Pisa thing was off the top of my... hat.

@GabrielePetronella Then a Duomo hat would serve the purpose pretty well, be happy.

Yes!
Italian.SE should participate in this year's Winter Bash. 

YES, I want a Pisa tower as a hat!

Nope!
Italian.SE should not participate. No hats for us!
